# Output the results of several SELECT statements to an excel sheet in their own columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a query that I want to turn into a stored proc which has, right now, about 6 select statements in it of similar data. Each one just brings back phone numbers in one column except each of the columns is named differently.

Basically it is:

```
SELECT PhoneNumber as PhoneGroup1 FROM PhoneNumberTable
SELECT PhoneNumber as PhoneGroup2 FROM PhoneNumberTable
SELECT PhoneNumber as PhoneGroup3 FROM PhoneNumberTable
```

It is actually more complex than that, but those are the results I get in a nutshell.

I then will go and copy/paste each column and its header name into a spreadsheet into Column A for PhoneGroup1, Column B for PhoneGroup2, etc.

```
PhoneGroup1 | PhoneGroup2 | PhoneGroup3
4856562281  | 9498675309  | 6238471273
7452837719  | 5739542855  | 4745856147
8472639273  | 6495232247  | 9516538847
```

Is there any way I can have this export to an excel sheet?

Thank you guys for any guidance!

Comment: You've got like three different (and major) questions in here.  Might be better to separate them out.

Comment: Your three questions 1) How can I get independent floating output into three different columns like PhoneGroup1, PhoneGroup2, PhoneGroup3. 2) How can I get my SQL output into an Excel spreadsheet? and 3) How can I mail query output or a file from SQL Server?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio you can click File > Save Results As... and that will save out a csv file which you can open in Excel.  Is that what you're looking for?  I find it easier to just select all on my result set and right click > Copy With Headers.  I then paste that into Excel.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have essentially been doing something similar by hand. Each of the select statements will bring back their own resultsets, though. So they are all in different mini-windows. That means I have to right click on each one, select all with headers, copy, go to excel, paste, then come back and do it with all six select statements. Going forward, I am anticipating several more columns as well and now the boss wants this everyday when I thought it would be a random thing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  Do you have something like this:

```
declare @tbl1 table ( id int )
declare @tbl2 table ( id int )

insert into @tbl1 values(1),(2),(3)
insert into @tbl2 values(10),(20),(30)

select * from @tbl1
union
select * from @tbl2
```

which returns this result set:

```
id
----
1
2
3
10
20
30
```

but you really want this result set?

```
id1  id2
---- ----
1    10
2    20
3    30
```

I can see a way to do this using row numbers.  Basically, you give each row returned from the individual tables a row number, and then you join the tables together matching on the row numbers.  It looks like this in my example:

```
declare @tbl1 table ( id int )
declare @tbl2 table ( id int )

insert into @tbl1 values(1),(2),(3)
insert into @tbl2 values(10),(20),(30)


select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
from
(
    select 'table1' as header, id, row_number() over (order by id) rnum
    from @tbl1 t1
) t1
inner join 
(
    select 'table2' as header, id, row_number() over (order by id) rnum
    from @tbl2 t2
) t2 on t1.rnum = t2.rnum
```

To add a column you have to add another join to the query.  If your tables have different numbers of rows and you want to see all rows, use <s>left</s> full outer joins instead of inner joins.

Comment: Thank you very much! This got me very close to what I wanted and I was able to use it just fine. You nailed it! :)